# Retrieving scientific names in a data frame

Tags: r

I need your help. is it possible to retrieve scientific names from common names in a data frame? I successfully tried it for only a single species record but failed for the whole data frame.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thacien, is there a dictionary available that would be used as a reference?

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/taxize/man/sci2comm.html

Comment: Hello @Phil, I am new to rStudio and unfortunately can not understand the meaning of the dictionary in the studio.  I tried the task using the Taxize R package but did not succeed with the data frame. Thank you

Comment: By dictionary, I just mean something to reference what the scientific words should be.

Comment: Oh, living organisms have both common names (vernacular names) and their scientific names. For example, Honey bee in English = uruyuki (in my local language) is a common name and its scientific name is an Apis mellifera (Latin language). Scientific names are the names that are accepted internationally and written in Latin language, they are not local names. Thank you so much.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking for a source to use as a reference. We cannot help you without something  to join this information.